# Is it possible to infer a typescript function argument's keys from the function body?

Tags: typescript

I'm writing many functions with a signature like

```
type MyFn<Keys extends string> = (arg: Record<Keys, any>) => any;
```

. I want to infer the individual strings in `Keys` based on each function's body. For example, if I wrote

```
function foo(bar) {
  return bar.baz + bar.quux
}
```

I'd like a way to infer that `bar` must have keys `"baz" | "quux"`. **Is inferring the argument type based on the function body possible?**. I strongly suspect it isn't, and I'd be interested to hear explanations why!

Comment: I'm confused by your example because in `foo`, the type `Keys` isn't generic or anything, it's apparently just some specific type, which either is `"baz" | "quux"` or it isn't.  Is that supposed to be generic somewhere? If so, what's the scope of the generic?

Comment: When is TypeScript supposed to know when to infer from the body or enforce the types for the body?

Comment: @jcalz I intentionally didn't mark `Keys` as a generic type since `<T extends string>(bar: {[T]: any}) => bar.baz` yields "Property 'baz' does not exist on type 'Record<Keys, any>'.(2339)";  [playground demo here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8BpApgTwM6JYAeUWYAJgXlAE4xgDmAfABQBGAhjQFyIBKWCHBrlMuPABpEHMDiYBKRAG8AUInWIaWKCBpJONAHScAXioC+QA). That could be a clue to @vr's point that TS may need to know argument types prior to gathering type constraints from the body.

Comment: Inference doesn't *declare* a type, and since `Keys` hasn't been declared there's going to be an error no matter what. That's the real reason why it can't possibly work *as written*.  Maybe you want to [edit] to say `function foo(bar) {return bar.baz + bar.quux}` and hope that `bar` could be contextually typed to be `{baz: any, quux: any}` instead of implicitly `any`? That still doesn't happen for you, but at least there wouldn't be this free-floating undeclared `Keys` type, and the answer for why it doesn't work would maybe involve inference.

Comment: Fair enough; editing now.
 
I'm looking for an answer as to why the contextual typing still doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible and probably will never be possible for the TypeScript compiler to contextually infer the type of an un-[annotated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) function parameter from its *usage* within the function body.  Suggestions to do this have consistently been declined; see [microsoft/TypeScript#15114](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15114), [microsoft/TypeScript#34738](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34738) , [microsoft/TypeScript#38992](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38992), for example, for authoritative reasons why.

According to those issues, it would be too expensive for the type checker to try to do such things automatically, as it would scale very poorly and interact badly with other inferences.  As the TS team dev lead [said in one of these issues](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34738#issuecomment-546489078):

> This has been an intentional design constraint since inception; *not* doing this is a key reason TS performance is remotely acceptable. The "infer from usage" refactor will produce a type for you on an as-requested basis.

---

Wait, what's that *"infer from usage" refactor*?  Well, it's a [quick fix](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/refactoring#_code-actions-quick-fixes-and-refactorings) that IntelliSense-enabled IDEs (e.g., VS Code, The TS Playground) can suggest.  Indeed, given your function:

```
function foo(bar) { // place cursor within bar 
  //  ---> ~~~
  // ^-- Quick fix... Infer parameter types from usage
  return bar.baz + bar.quux;
}
```

if you place your cursor inside the unannotated `bar` parameter, you should get an "infer parameter types from usage" quick fix prompt.  If you run that refactoring, it produces this:

```
function foo(bar: { baz: any; quux: any; }) {
  return bar.baz + bar.quux;
}
```

so `bar` gains an annotated type of `{ baz: any; quux: any }`, which is essentially what you wanted.  The reason why this is possible for a quick fix and not as part of the TypeScript type checker is that it's a manual opt-in process that is necessarily limited in scope because it can't trigger an expanding cascade of effects.

---

Maybe such a quick fix isn't ideal for your use case, but it might at least be better than having to manually write out the type yourself for each function.  But even if not, at least we know that your desired behavior is intentionally not implemented, and why.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.2#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkqJLAsgEIQBmA9gE4QCKArgJbwDWAYmwB55CRJNRbB4AFza1gI2rQAUAIxD0AlHiQB6LUhgZySeC3pQGSAO5sJACzayV9JEOHbdgXg3AhTtIAtH4B8SAB+IS7COkgAen5IrBycIvwAdClIAJLA1BBOcPTgEBLZSBIAnjDQIvS0YEgsUCAA5hBhRIwSJg6qSSo4ANRIjkkAjiwsfADcYQC+QjNEJNBwiEgAgtSF9HFcvAIErqLiUjJyio4AXJo9FyDAJeNII2PXt-dTGnuuSG0dA109SP1Bo8JtNZvgpkA)

Answer (score 1):

> TypeScript adds optional static typing to Javascript, it provides static typing through type annotations to enable type checking **at compile time**.

So TypeScript can infer the type of the argument object based on the function signature, but it cannot infer the individual strings in the Keys based on the function body

When you define a function with the signature type

```js
MyFn<Keys extends string> = (arg: Record<Keys, any>) => any
```

You are indicating that the function takes an objet with keys of type `Keys` and values of type `any`. However, without additional context, TypeScript has no way to know what the keys of the object should be.